# How do you do a System Restore in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

How can I restore my Windows 7, as it is creating too many issues for me now? I can do the task for the Windows XP, but I do not know how to do this in Windows 7.

Comment: The process should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Boot from the Windows DVD or Press F8 and [select the computer repair options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7).

Here select System Restore:

[image]